# Batch file can not run successfully in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, ssis

In my task, I call DTEXEC /F to run an SSIS package which includes executing batch file error. But when I can run the batch file in command window successfully.
And I traced the SSIS package's process. It shows run this batch file fail.
Is there anybody faced same issues? How to resolve it?
Thanks

Comment: just write the full path of DTEXEC in your batch file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "[packagePath]\[packageName].dtsx"

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I already included the full path for that in my SSIS package. My question is I can run the same batch file in the command window. But when I run the SSIS package which includes the same batch file at first step. It can't continue success. Thanks.